# A field with quadratically closed extensions

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Is there an example of a field $K$ of characteristic not $2$, all of whose finite extensions are quadratically closed? And what can we say about its cohomological dimension (I want it to be bigger than 1)?

Comment: Probably that would force the field to be algebraically closed, though I'm not sure.

Comment: Let $p>2$ be a prime. Let $K$ be the (nested) union of the finite fields $\Bbb{F}_{p^{2^m}}$, $m\in\Bbb{N}$. Obviously inside the algebraic closure of $\Bbb{F}_p$. Then all the finite extensions of $K$ have an odd degree. Furthermore, every odd number $\ell$ is the degree of the unique extension, namely the compositum $K\Bbb{F}_{p^\ell}$. Cannot say anything about the cohomological dimension of this $K$. Probably too simple to suit you.

Comment: I interpret *quadratically closed* to mean *a field that has no extensions of degree two*. Observe that the example $K$ in my first comment is not algebraically closed.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen Thanks a lot for your example, that's interesting!